# How can I copy in or include other GitHub users to an issue?

Tags: github

When I create a new GitHub Issue, I can assign a user. Then both myself and this user will then become participants in the Issue and receive updates.

I sometimes want other users to also receive notifications on the ticket even if they are not the current assignee. How can I add other users to the Issue at the time of Issue creation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to include their username in the issue.

> [When you @mention a GitHub username anywhere in the context of an issue or pull request, that person is notified and subscribed to future updates.](https://github.com/blog/821)

So if you wanted a GitHub user by the username, **tornadosandwich**, to be notified that you want them to see the issue, just put **@tornadosandwich** in the body of the issue and it will notify them.

> Would like to know what **@tornadosandwich** thinks about this.

This will only work if the user has allowed it. If they never respond or acknowledge being included they may have unchecked both boxes in their account settings under the Notification Center:

> Participating
>   When you participate in a discussion or someone brings you in with an @mention.